# QEMU on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, qemu, arm

I'm trying to eventually run a Debian image within Raspian, but for now I'm just trying to run Slitaz.  I'm able to get the boot process going, but it hangs while loading 'rootfs(N).gz, where (N) is 1-4.  With some memory tweaking, I'm able to get it to the 'Decompressing Linux' stage, yet it hangs there now and I've not been able to figure out a workaround.

I made a 2 GB qcow2 .img for the .iso, and tried allocating as much as 386 MB of RAM.  It still black screens and I can't even sudo kill the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I barely remember this question, but I was able to use this on a different, more powerful ARM.   (SPH-L900, IIRC.)  Turns out that the Pi *can* do it, but it would take almost literally forever to load, so I can imagine what actual use would look like.